when to take express rows in matrix, and when as columns.
Usually in my class, we express them as columns of the matrix but only for some questions are the vectors taken as rows, but even then the method for calculating row and column spaces didn't change. If $4$ vectors $\in \mathbb{R}^5$ are given which of the spaces(row,column and null) belongs to $\mathbb{R}^5$ and which of those belongs to $\mathbb{R}^4$. This may help me understand how to represent them.

It would be helpful if you could give specific examples of questions where you're not sure how to represent a vector. In the end of the day though, the answer is in some part going to be that it is a matter of preference.

The last two sentences of your question don't seem related to the rest of your question in an obvious way

The last two sentences were also meant to represent the same thing. My thought was that if the basis of the row space always belongs to the same dimensional space as the vectors, then I will have to represent vectors as rows, or if the column space satisfies that, then I have to represent them as columns. Hope this conveys what I was thinking.

Why should the dimension of the space of the vector determine whether that vector is a row or a column? It sounds like you're saying something like "vectors in $\Bbb R^4$ are always rows and vectors in $\Bbb R^5$ are always columns". Also, when you say "4 vectors in $\Bbb R^5$", do you mean a $5 \times 4$ matrix?
